# Which Preference Class for an Integer?

Tags: android, android-preferences

To store an integer in an Android preference, I would intuitively go for `EditTextPreference` and do the usual String-int-String conversions.

But then I came across a piece of code that stores an integer in a `<ListPreference>` instead:

```
<ListPreference 
  android:key="@string/total_score"
  android:defaultValue="0" />
```

and retrieves it using `preferences.getInt(getString(R.string.total_score), 0);`

Does this really work? If so, how?

Is it considered acceptable practice?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the answers below, I have been able to find the implementation source code for [getInt()](http://google.com/codesearch#zK3VeWq4s9c/trunk/android-cpp-sdk/platforms/android-7/android/content/SharedPreferences.hpp&q=SharedPreferences%20package:android&type=cs). I am posting it here for easy reference:

```
jint android::content::SharedPreferences::getInt(local_ref< java::lang::String > const &a0, jint a1)
{
        return call_method<
                android::content::SharedPreferences::J2CPP_CLASS_NAME,
                android::content::SharedPreferences::J2CPP_METHOD_NAME(2),
                android::content::SharedPreferences::J2CPP_METHOD_SIGNATURE(2),
                jint
        >(get_jobject(), a0, a1);
}
```

Comment: Try my [NumberPickerPreference](https://gist.github.com/afarber/609c4b2ce52a6ae41453)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory, yes you can store an integer with a `ListPreference`. After all it's a UI-preference that maps a user displayed label/key (`android:entries`) to an internal value (`android:entryValues`) and displays all those mapping options in a listview. That internal value might as well be an integer. You could use a `<integer-array>`-resource for the entryValues.

In practice, I've never seen that work - it's [bugged](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2096).
Of course, you can set a int value to the preference key of the `ListPreference` in your code, since it's a normal preference internally. But that would defeat the whole purpose of predefined resource arrays and ability to select from a list. As a workaround, if a int-array would be handy, I recommend using a `<string-array>` for the values and convert them an integer in code, as you would with your `EditTextPreference`

*Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227478/getting-integer-or-index-values-from-a-list-preference) for a non-working example. ;)*

**To answer your title question which one to choose for an integer: Depends.**

You can use either one with the workarounds.

If the user should be able to enter *any* value (or just a lot of values), the `EditTextPreference` is the way to go. A `ListPreference` would just be too long.

If you have a small set of predefined ints, use a `ListPreference`. Thats way more comfortable to use and might be displayed with useful labels. Example: If the user is supposed to select a timing interval, you could map the seconds in the value and display a different label, e.g. an hour [value 3600; label "Hour"].

---

**Edit:** Also got an idea where your code snippet may be related to. Since this `ListPreference` does neither specify `android:entries` nor `android:entryValues`, it might just be part of a default preference file. You can use [`PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29) with an XML file to reset/initalize all your preference keys. In this case it's completely random which preference you choose, because all fields that count are `android:key` and `android:defaultValue`. You might use any other type in this case, does not matter.

Comment: Your analysis is excellent (+1) but I am struggling with the conclusion: If "it's bugged" and "would defeat the whole purpose", why are you still considering it as an option? BTW, I failed to mention that in my case the preference would NOT be editable by the user (only the program code stores and reads it).

Comment: I struggled a bit with my grammar in this post so maybe I was not so clear. Short: `ListPreference` with an `<integer-array>` is **not** an option. It does not work. `ListPreference` with strings that contain parseable integers are the workaround. They are an option, since the extra work is almost non-existant.

Comment: Thanks + 1 again. It is clear now. BTW, I was trying to find the source code for SharedPreferences.getInt() but all I found was [this](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/content/SharedPreferences.java/?v=source), which doesn't show any implementation. Any idea where I can find the implementation, so that I can learn directly from the source code?

Comment: Also: Your preference is not editable by the user. That confuses me, why do you need a EditTextPreference or a ListPreference? Both (and everything that extends the `Preference` class) are basically prebuilt UI components which are intended to let the user edit preferences easily. If just your app edits these settings, why don't you just rely on `SharedPreferences.get[datatype]()` and `SharedPreferences.Editor.put[datatype]()`?

Comment: To find code: The whole android code is available on android.git.kernel.org. But a more convinient way to search it is google.com/codesearch. Just put "android" in the package field and "SharedPreferences" in the searchbox, first hit. :)

Comment: Answering your very good question: I *am* using `SharedPreferences.getInt()` but I am helping it with the built-in XML support for the following reasons: (1) Establish a default in XML (2) Prepare for a scenario in which I would like to open it to user editing (e.g. developer/technician version). Otherwise, you are right of course, but I would still want to understand what classes are allowed (under the cover) for supporting `SharedPreferences.getInt()`. BTW, Google's code search only yields the **interface**, not the implementation. I would love to see the C++ code.

Comment: Ops, didn't check that. If you want the c++ code, you have to dig in the git repo. :) Etablishing default in XML: See my edit, if you didn't notice yet. Apart from that, I guess I cant help anymore. Never dug that deep into the preference code, so can't tell much about the internals.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on is that the `ListPreference` is storing the entry values as an array of chars, or in other words an array of bytes (I'm inferring this from the [setEntryValues(CharSequence[] entryValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntryValues%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D%29) method).  This could be why storing a number works, because the value is stored into the byte array, so using the `preferences.getInt(...)` method will still work.  This could be dangerous, however, as discrepancies with signing could occur, so I wouldn't recommend it, and would parse the int from a string preference instead.

Comment: Thanks + 1. What you're saying makes sense (parse the int from a string) but then what is the purpose of [getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [similar convenience methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getFloat%28java.lang.String,%20float%29)?

Comment: getInt() simply looks for the value pointed to by the key (which is what getString() provides), similar to a hashmap.  My guess is that the getInt() might not provide any validation on whether the returned value (pointed to by the 'key' from getString()) is in fact an int at all.  An interesting test would be to see if getInt() succeeds in grabbing a value from a charsequence (try 'a' and see if it returns 97).

Comment: Thanks + 1 again. I noticed that you used the words "My guess". Any idea where I can find the **implementation** source code of [SharedPreferences.getInt()](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/content/SharedPreferences.java/?v=source) so that I can learn directly from the source code?

Comment: Theres a lot to look through, but the HEAD of their source code for the interface on the git repo is here:  http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java;hb=HEAD  if I knew where to look or if I find it I'll post again here.

Comment: Should also be noted that the docs indicate that a ClassCastException will be thrown if the value is not an int (which it obviously isn't doing if the code above works.  Or maybe it isn't working?).

Comment: Yup. It's still the **interface** code. :) I found a [SharedPreferences.hpp](http://google.com/codesearch#zK3VeWq4s9c/trunk/android-cpp-sdk/platforms/android-7/android/content/SharedPreferences.hpp&q=SharedPreferences%20package:android&type=cs) but not the C++ implementation yet. As for the `ClassCastException`, yes I am receiving (and handling it). I am trying to understand this.