# Android SharedPreferences integer-array of values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use SharedPreferences as follows

in arrays.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="empty_array"/>

    <string-array name="baseLayers">
        <item>Normal</item>
        <item>Hyrbid</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>Terrain</item>
    </string-array>

    <integer-array name="baseLayerValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>      
    </integer-array>
...
```

Then in preferences:

```
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="MAPS" >
        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/baseLayers"
            android:entryValues="@array/baseLayerValues"
            android:key="baseLayer"
            android:title="Base Layer" />
   ...
```

But I get an exception when I try and use the settings menu to select a new option:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.preference.ListPreference.onDialogClosed(ListPreference.java:264)
    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onDismiss(DialogPreference.java:390)
    at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1233)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?  Is it possible to use an integer-array as an array of values in this case?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5227514/2399024

Comment: Wow so string only. Looks to be pretty old issue that many people struggled with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your arrays.xml file just change the `integer-array` to `string-array` and you are good.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="empty_array"/>

    <string-array name="baseLayers">
        <item>Normal</item>
        <item>Hyrbid</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>Terrain</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="baseLayerValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>      
    </string-array>
```

If you want to get the item programmatically you have to parse the String to int like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("baseLayer", 0); // the 0 is the default value
int x = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("baseLayer", "0"));
```